# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when dismiss a customized login view

Tags: iphone, uiview, sdk, exc-bad-access

I have the following code in the main AppDelegate.m calling a my own class (UIViewController type) used for login process:

```
    #import "Auth.h"
    @class Auth;
    ...
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
    Auth *viewController = [Auth alloc];
    [_window addSubview:viewController.view];
    return YES;
```

}

After allocating the view (**not included on the storyboard**) with:

```
  self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
  <add button and other things>
```

It is displayed correctly within a button.

The problem arises when I need to dismiss it in order to follow the "normal" flux formed by the other views associated to the storyboard (three ViewControllers already well connected).

From within the mentioned button I tried with both:

```
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and

```
   [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

but I always receive:

EXC_BAD_ACCESS on

```
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { @autoreleasepool {
     return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
   }}
```

Can anyone help me?
Thank you very much in advance.

---

I tried all your suggestions without success.
Probably some other issue with delegation.
How can I define the delegate for my Auth class?
Thank you.

Comment: Try again with `NSZombieEnabled`.

Comment: Didn't you forget `init` on `Auth` class?

Answer (score 0):

Also set an Exception Breakpoint within XCode 4 to trap this exception and further investigate the current stack trace.

You can set this breakpoint from the Breakpoint Navigator pane of XCode, click the lower left '+' and add an Exception Breakpoint.

Comment: I tried all your suggestions without success.
BTW, I have no the removeFromsuperView from within the Auth class view.
I'm supposing this is not the right way in order to optionally load this view or following those defined on the storyboard.
I would simply load the Auth class view when a variable is zero (by evaluating it on the AppDelegate), otherwise not.
Moreover, loading the storyboard path after user has defined its data on the login process.

Any other ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi all, I solved by adding a UIView on the StoryBoard then using: `Auth *login = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Auth"];
        [self presentModalViewController:login animated:YES];`. At this point `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` from within Auth succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Eimantas is right that you generally never call `alloc` on something without immediately calling its designated initializer (`init` or `initWithFrame` or whatever it is). That is very strange; I'd look at that first.

Or, if you're intending to have that view controller have a view get added to the primary window, why not have the primary window .xib just designate the class of File's Owner to be Auth?

Comment: Hi all, I solved by adding a UIView on the StoryBoard then using: `Auth *login = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Auth"];
        [self presentModalViewController:login animated:YES];`. At this point `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` from within Auth succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding a UIView on the StoryBoard then using:

```
   Auth *login = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Auth"]; 
   [self presentModalViewController:login animated:YES];
```

At this point

```
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

from within Auth succeeded.